# Why is the code not passing the unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

This is the code:

```
# mean_var-_std.py
def calculate(list):
    if len(list) < 9:
        print("List must contain nine numbers.")
        raise ValueError
    else:
        return 0
```

This is the unit-test:

```
import unittest
import mean_var_std


# the test case
class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_calculate_with_few_digits(self):
        self.assertRaisesRegex(ValueError, "List must contain nine numbers.", mean_var_std.calculate, [2,6,2,8,4,0,1,])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This is the error that I get:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_calculate_with_few_digits (test_module.UnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/fcc-mean-var-std-2/test_module.py", line 8, in test_calculate_with_few_digits
    self.assertRaisesRegex(ValueError, "List must contain nine numbers.", mean_var_std.calculate, [2,6,2,8,4,0,1,])
AssertionError: "List must contain nine numbers." does not match ""

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I don't understand what `AssertionError: "List must contain nine numbers." does not match ""` means. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function raises an error without error message. It also *prints* a message but that’s unrelated (and generally seen as bad practice).

Remove the `print` statement and raise an error with an error message to fix the unit test failure:

```
def calculate(list):
    if len(list) < 9:
        raise ValueError("List must contain nine numbers.")
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small modification in the code.

```
def calculate(list):
    if len(list) < 9:
        print("List must contain nine numbers.")
        raise ValueError("List must contain nine numbers.")
    else:
        return 0
```

Since you're looking for ValueError, the unittest will not look at your print statement.